# Convert number to corresponding words in Russian

Tags: formatting, linguistics

Is there any package that can convert any number to words in Russian? 
For example, I want to type something like this:

```
\mysum=5000000
\numprint{\the\mysum} ₽ (\Numtotxt{\the\mysum} рублей)
```

And to get something like this:

```
5 000 000 ₽ (Пять миллионов рублей)
```

I tried to use `fmtcount`, `moreenum` and `numname`, but all attempts failed.

Comment: Maybe the `numnameru` package will do the trick? https://ctan.org/pkg/numnameru

Comment: @AlanMunn It worked, thanks! If you make it not a comment, but an answer, I will be able to accept it as the solution.

Comment: Perhaps easier is if you make an answer yourself with a sample document showing how it works, since I don't know any Russian.

Comment: @AlanMunn, I posted the answer. But there is a conflict between `\numnameru` and `\MakeUppercase`, which I do not know how to manage.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to comment by @AlanMunn: the package `numnameru` does the job.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{numnameru}
\usepackage{numprint}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Georgia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\begin{document}
    \numprint{5000000} (\numnameru{5000000})
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: 5 000 000 (пять миллионов)]

But... The standards require that the first letter is uppercase. And  `\MakeUppercase \numnameru{5000000}` gives an error :-(

Comment: The original `numname` functionality in `memoir` had uppercase versions of the `\numtoname` command, but it doesn't seem to be part of the Russian version. The code isn't that difficult to implement, just boring, so it wouldn't be too hard to add that functionality to the package. You can look at the `numname.sty` code.